No module named 'smbclient' (smbprotocol) after installing my package (build from a poetry project)
I add smbprotocol with poetry add smbprotocol (smbprotocol). This installs modules 'smbprotocol' and 'smbclient' in my environment:

site-packages/smbprotocol
site-packages/smbclient

When I build my project poetry build and install my package. Then I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smbclient' error.
poetry show and poetry run pip list only shows smbprotocol. Installing smbclient doesn't work, since this module comes with smbprotocol.
How can I tell poetry, configure my pyproject.toml, to also include smbclient?
I tried:
packages = [{ include = "smbclient" },]

But this tries to include smbclient from my source-tree, while it's located in my site-packages.
